# TypeError: fn is not a function at $parseFunctionCall

Tags: angularjs

I am intrested to know why there is this behaviour.

This code:

```
$scope.showIntersecting = function(mode) {
    $scope.show = false;
    elementsManager.showIntersecting(mode, $scope.menuObject);
    displaySituation.display();
}
```

is throwing following error:   
 
TypeError: fn is not a function    
 
at $parseFunctionCall (/angular/angular.js:12331:15)at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback(/angular/angular.js:22940:17)   
 
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (/angular/angular.js:14381:28)   
 
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (/angular/angular.js:14480:23)   
 
at HTMLAnchorElement. (/angular/angular.js:22945:23)   
 
at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.js:4430:9)   
 
at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.js:4116:28) undefined

This code is working properly:

```
$scope.showIntersectingAirways = function() {
    $scope.show = false;
    elementsManager.showIntersecting('airways', $scope.menuObject);
    displaySituation.display();
};
```

Html code is as shown here

```
     <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" ng-show="showIntersectingFlights" ng-click="showIntersecting('something')">Show intersecting something</a></li>
```

Show intersecting something

Comment: It strongly depends what parameter fails. Could you log on the console all needed parameters before executing failing function?

Comment: The parameter "mode" is a simple string - "sectors" for example. After more investigation turns out that the solution was to simply rename the function. After the name was changed to "$scope.showIntersections = function(mode)....." it worked normally. I still don't understand why this behavior. Still would like an answer.  Using the debug, i also observed that not even the first line on the function was not reached. Thanks

Comment: Then I think this is your problem - remove href="#" and let me know if it works

Comment: After removing href="#" same error as I shown is thrown. No change at all. I am also guessing that is my problem in some way, but can' t see it. I have no other function in this scope with the same name, so can not be a name conflict.